# Using Imperative API with functional component

Tags: react-native, lottie

Is there a way to make use of the Imperative API on [Lottie View]https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native with functional components?

I am using the Lottie View component as following. I would like an easy way to call the play() and stop() methods. I'm hoping there is a way to do it without converting this component to a class.

```
const GameInterface: React.FunctionComponent<GameInterfaceProps> = () => {
    return (
        <LottieView
            source={require('./Data/data.json')}
        />
    );
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 // TODO: add an explanation


 const GameInterface = (props: {lottieViewRef: (ref: any) => void}) => {

    return (
        <LottieView
            source={require('./Data/data.json')}
            ref={(ref) => props.lottieViewRef(ref)}
        />
    );
};


const YourApp = () => {

    let gameRef = useRef(null);      

    return (
      <View style={styles.myBeautifullStyle}>
         <GameInterface 
           lottieViewRef={(ref) => gameRef = ref} 
         />
         <Button 
           onClick={() => gameRef.play()}
         />    
      </View>
    );

}
```

Comment: This approach does seem to work. My only problem now is it seems only gameRef.play() will work. When I call the other methods I get "gameRef.pause is not a function". Would this be a problem with my implementation or something on Lottie's end?

Comment: Update: I was using an older version of Lottie. I updated and I'm good to go. Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: This won't work since 'gameRef' is 'const' and you are assigning 'ref' to a constant.